# IntelliJ: foreach Live Template code formatting

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ idea when I insert the foreach live template it will put newline after ':' so it will look like this:

```
  for ( :
    ) {

    }
```

I want to have the for statement on one line like this:

```
  for ( : ) {

  }
```

I tried to change my code formatting preferences, but could not figure out what setting influences this particular case.

So my question is how to set code style options to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the `iter` live template rather than the `foreach`. `foreach` is under the Android block, and the default style for that is what adds the newline.

**Update:**

As of at least 2018.1.1 (not sure when it was added), you can now type the `<name of your collection>.for` *then tab* and it will expand out into a foreach loop.

It's also brought in the same surrounding/expansion for stuff like `<array>.stream` *then tab* and probably a few others I'm not aware of.

Comment: why did they call it `iter`? I mean, yeah, it iterates, but if I want a foreach-loop, I'm gonna start with typing for...

Comment: @Xerus `foreach` and `fori` were already taken by other templates. Given what the feature in Java is called "enhanced for loop" there's no wonder it's confusing. You can rename/replace the templates though so maybe `fore`.

Comment: I didn't find any other template for `foreach` tho? So yeah, I renamed it to foreach

Comment: @Xerus you probably didn't have Android plugin installed, that's where the `foreach` is from.

I've noticed that Intellij at least as of 2018.1.1, you can now type the `<name of your collection>.for` then `tab` and it will expand out into a foreach loop.

It's also brought in the same surrounding/expansion for stuff like `<array>.stream` and probably a few others I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 16):

- Go to *File* -> *Settings* -> *Editor* -> *Code Style* -> *Live Template*.
- At the right side open **Android** list and stay on **foreach** .
- In the Options area uncheck **Reformat according to style**.

You can see how to do it in the IntelliJ IDEA settings [foreach style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw9Ws.jpg)

Comment: Worked for me, Good answer!

Answer (score 7):

You can change the template for the enhanced `for` loop in IntelliJ by changing the setting in Live Templates.

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates.  In the right side, choose iterations -> "iter (Iterate Iterable | Array in J2SDK 5.0 syntax)".  At the bottom you can see the template text and you can change it by introducing the newline where you want it.  Change

```
for ($ELEMENT_TYPE$ $VAR$ : $ITERABLE_TYPE$) {
    $END$
}
```

to

```
for ($ELEMENT_TYPE$ $VAR$ :
     $ITERABLE_TYPE$) {
  $END$
}
```

and apply your changes.

In the source code editor, choose Code -> Insert Live Template... -> iter, then IntelliJ will insert the code template as you've specified, with boxes around the variable names for changing them.

```
for (String arg :
        args)
{

}
```

Comment: I think you mixed up what the default and what OP wants.